# Incredibly slow Materialized View creation when using string aggregation, any performance suggestions?

Tags: oracle10g, materialized-views, string-aggregation

I've got a load of materialized views, some of them take just a few seconds to create and refresh, whereas others can take me up to 40 minutes to compile, if SQLDeveloper doesn't crash before that.

I need to aggregate some strings in my query, and I have the following function

```
create or replace
function stragg
  ( input varchar2 )
  return varchar2
  deterministic
  parallel_enable
  aggregate using stragg_type
;
```

Then, in my MV I use a select statement such as

```
SELECT
  hse.refno,
  STRAGG (DISTINCT per.person_name) as PERSONS
FROM
 HOUSES hse,
 PERSONS per
```

This is great, because it gives me the following :

```
 refno        persons
 1            Dave, John, Mary
 2            Jack, Jill
```

Instead of :

```
 refno        persons
 1            Dave
 1            John
 1            Mary
 2            Jack 
 2            Jill
```

It seems that when I use this `STRAGG` function, the time it takes to create/refresh an MV increases dramatically. Is there an alternative method to achieve a comma separate list of values? I use this throughout my MVs so it is quite a required feature for me

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's `stragg`'s fault? What's the plan for the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of techniques for string aggregation at the link below. They might provide better performance for you.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've tried `WM_CONCAT` but its even slower than `STRAGG`, but about 100%. Might have to try some customized options as described there